# exercise package; how to get counter for a custom exercise type to increment with memoir sections?

Tags: memoir, counters, exercises, chngcntr

Just started learning LaTeX, because I'm trying to write a short math book. I started out using LyX, but ultimately I want more control over the typesetting, so I have to learn LaTeX.

Anyway, I want the `\newenvironment{Example}` that I defined to update its counter in the same way that `\exercise` does.

`\exercise` updates the way I want it to when I use `\counterwithin{Exercise}{section}`, but it does not work when I use `\counterwithin{Example}{section}`. I have no idea what the problem is, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code that illustrates my problem:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{exercise,chngcntr}


\begin{document}

%Memoir
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}


\chapter{Chapter name}
\section{Section1}

\newcounter{Example}

\counterwithin{Exercise}{section} %Ties exercises counter to memoir section?
\counterwithin{Example}{section} %Use this to tie the example counter to the memoir sections?

\newenvironment{Example}{\begin{Exercise}[name={Example},
counter={Example}]}
{\end{Exercise}}

%Exercises below:

\begin{Exercise}
Exercise text
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Example}
Example text
\end{Example}

\begin{Exercise} %counter is the way I want it to be
Exercise text
\end{Exercise}

\section{Section2}

\begin{Exercise}
Exercise text
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Example}
Example text
\end{Example}

\begin{Example} %Counter does not increment
Example text
\end{Example}

\begin{Exercise}
Exercise text
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

Edit: For clarification, the problem is in the second section, Section2, where the Example doesn't update: Example 2.1.1 and then Example 2.1.1 again, instead of Example 2.1.1 and then Example 2.1.2.

Comment: Try to move `\counterwithin{Example}{section}` after you define the `Example` environment.

Comment: @Sigur I tried. Examples still don't increment.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Please, give some example with numeration. Your code produces here **Exercise 1.1.1 Example 1.1.1 Exercise 1.1.2**. It makes sense since the section is 1.1. Do you want **Example 1.1.2** instead of?

Comment: Not for me, I only see Exercise 1, etc. Not starting again with a new section.

Comment: @MaxNoe, ow, now I see the problem. It is in Section 2.

Comment: *off topic*: don't mix code from preamble with text body. Move the definitions to preamble.

Comment: @MaxNoe My bad for not clarifying. Edited OP for clarity.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the package.

Comment: @Sigur I see. I can get the `amsthm` package to do what I want using `\theoremstyle`, but then I don't have automatic answers to exercises. Do you know of any way to get answers to exercises using some `ams`-type package?

Comment: Exsheets is a great package

Answer (score 1):

The `exercise` package offers the command `\renewcounter{<counter>}[<resetcounter>]` to modify the behaviour of predefined counters.

So you need to add `\renewcounter{Exercise}[section]` to your preamble.

Comment: Tried this but it didn't make example increment in the second section.